# How to generate a date sequence format dd/mm/yy or %d%m%y?

Tags: r, date, seq

normally I use this:

```
seq(as.Date("01/01/1964"), as.Date("01/12/1964"), "months", format = "%d%m%Y", tz = "UTC")
```

but I'm receiving this:

```
[1] "0001-01-19" "0001-02-19" "0001-03-19" "0001-04-19" "0001-05-19" "0001-06-19" "0001-07-19" "0001-08-19" "0001-09-19"
[10] "0001-10-19" "0001-11-19" "0001-12-19"
```

I try lubridate and others tips from others ans, but not works.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

@r2evans ans:

```
format(seq(as.Date('1964/01/01'), as.Date('1964/12/01'), 'months'), format="%d-%m-%Y", tz="UTC")
 [1] "01-01-1964" "01-02-1964" "01-03-1964" "01-04-1964" "01-05-1964" "01-06-1964" "01-07-1964" "01-08-1964" "01-09-1964"
[10] "01-10-1964" "01-11-1964" "01-12-1964"
```

Comment: Try `seq(as.Date("1964-01-01"), as.Date("1964-12-01"), "month")`

Comment: @r2evans help me, works with format(......., format = ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `help(as.Date)`:

> format: A character string. If not specified, it will try '"%Y-%m-%d"' then '"%Y/%m/%d"' on the first non-'NA' element.

For debugging, it would have been informative to try:

```
as.Date("01/01/1964")
## [1] "0001-01-19"
```

from which you could have quickly deduced that it was mis-identifying your fields.

If you have control over your start/end date format, then simply change it:

```
seq(as.Date("1964/01/01"), as.Date("1964/12/01"), "months", format = "%d%m%Y", tz = "UTC")
## [1] "1964-01-01" "1964-02-01" "1964-03-01" "1964-04-01" "1964-05-01" "1964-06-01"
## [7] "1964-07-01" "1964-08-01" "1964-09-01" "1964-10-01" "1964-11-01" "1964-12-01"
```

Though the `format=` parameter isn't working (`seq` doesn't use it). Wrap the whole thing with `format` to get the strings you appear to want, though realize that these will no longer be of `Date` class:

```
format(seq(as.Date('1964/01/01'), as.Date('1964/12/01'), 'months'), format="%Y%m%d", tz="UTC")
## [1] "19640101" "19640201" "19640301" "19640401" "19640501" "19640601" "19640701"
## [8] "19640801" "19640901" "19641001" "19641101" "19641201"
```

If, however, you do not have control over the format of the start/stop dates, then add a `format=` parameter (and `tz=` if necessary) to each `as.Date`:

```
seq(as.Date('01/01/1964', format='%d/%m/%Y'), as.Date('01/12/1964', format='%d/%m/%Y'), 'months')
## [1] "1964-01-01" "1964-02-01" "1964-03-01" "1964-04-01" "1964-05-01" "1964-06-01"
## [7] "1964-07-01" "1964-08-01" "1964-09-01" "1964-10-01" "1964-11-01" "1964-12-01"
```

and use `format` as above, if needed.

Comment: the result that I wait is: [1] "01-01-1964" "01-02-1964" "01-03-1964" "01-04-1964"....etc

is a Brazilian date format

Comment: Doesn't `format(..., format="%d-%m-%Y", tz="UTC")` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

A solution in base R is

```
my.format <- "%d/%m/%Y"
seq(as.Date("01/01/1964", format = my.format),
    as.Date("01/12/1964", format = my.format),
    "months")
```

basically, you missed the `"/"`.

Furthermore, as pointed out, using ISO standard notation for Date (eg `YYYY-MM-DD`) simplifies a lot.

Comment: the result that I wait is:

    [1] "01-01-1964" "01-02-1964" "01-03-1964" "01-04-1964"....etc